# Difference between writing OpenCV for Android(Mobile devices) and writing openCV for Desktop Application(OpenCV 2.4.3 usingC++)

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, java-native-interface

I was doing face detection and recognition project.I am about to finish the application which does detection and recognition. I want to make this application portable like a one that works on Mobile devices. I am new to writing codes using OpenCV on Androids. ***What is the difference between OpenCV codes for Android phones and OpenCV written for Desktop application using C++ on Visual Studio like VS 2010 with Open CV 2.4.3?(What is the difference between Codes between OpenCV on Android and OpenCV for Desktop.Do they both use the same language?)*** 
I am familiar with Android(basics) and true that Android applications are written with Java. And i read somewhere online that OpenCV native codes can be included to Android with *Java Native Interface.*
**I am a bit confused here that can i use the code i have written using C++ Open CV for my Android Application with out modification.If not what Kind of modification do i have to make on my face detection and recognition using C++ for Desktop to make it work for Android phones?**

Comment: Yeah... You could use it using ndk, opencv gives a quite a good documentation for this

Answer (score 6):

First off, there exists an [OpenCV4Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-usage-models.html) version of Android, with tutorials on how to use it.

Then, as you pointed out, you can code both in Java or C++ on Android. OpenCV4Android can be used in Java [[1](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)] or in C++ [[2](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c)]. In your case, it would probably be more convenient to re-use your C++ code, using the [Native Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) for Android. If you manage to use the NDK, **you will be able to re-use your C++ code by calling it from your Android app.**

Here are the few steps I would advise you to follow:

- Read about the [Native Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)
- Read about the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNI)
- Try to create a sample Android app using C++ (You might find [this quickstart tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/nakhrq?i=1&p=1&q=&t%5B%5D=%21%21mine&t%5B%5D=%21%21bookmarks) useful)
- Try to integrate OpenCV to your sample [[2](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c)]
- Include your existing C++ code in your sample

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I used OpenCV on Android using both Java and C++. From my experience, I can suggest to **use Native C++ code** for image processing application. C++ codes are **more efficient** and can give **more identical result** as compared to Java code.

Although OpenCV has the Java version also, but in the back-end, it is using Native code for running Java.

The **speed of execution** in Native code will be much high as compared to Java code.