# identifying eyes from images

Tags: android, opencv, eye-detection

i am upto recognizing the eye in an image (which is opened).The image is taken by the camera Activity in a tablet.By webservice i could connect it to postgres.But i dont know how i should consider those images to identify the eyes.when i searched i came across OpenCV but im new to it..is there any particular algorithm (name) to identify the eye..when i searched they said its possible in android with the help of opencv by simply importing some packages..but i dont know how to start and from where..can any one plz help me..Something supporting android will be helpful..

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, there are few differences between the CV4Android library and the OpenCV C++ library. In addition, C++ code can be used by using the [Native Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) for Android.

With that being said, OpenCV has a C++ tutorial that uses Cascade Classifiers to identify an individual's face and eyes and places a circle around each one of the eyes and a larger circle around the head.

[image: Face Detection Example]

The tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html).

Edit: If you're looking for more information on the CV4Android and OpenCV C++ libraries, I'd recommend reading the reply to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124681/difference-between-writing-opencv-for-androidmobile-devices-and-writing-opencv) question. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply...i will go through the same...but i juz want to ask is it will be safe enough to go with open cv in android..what i meant is i dont know c++..and i hav only very little time to meet my aim.is i possible to connect a normal android app with opencv app..plzz help me to come out of this mess..

Comment: is it possible to process the image (taken by our camera activity app) by the open cv.Actually im very doubtful whenever i read the following [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)  someone plz help me is it a right choice to go with opencv.is it possible for opencv to process the image taken by my camera app that work on alarm manager..